# Ceramic capacitor in High voltage DC link

Tags: capacitor, motor, power-electronics, high-voltage

In motor drive application the high voltage dc link between the rectifier and the inverter usually have:

- a bank of aluminium electrolytic capacitor
- a film capacitor near the inverter

[image]

Is there a reason for using a film capacitor on the high voltage dc link instead of a ceramic capacitor?

Are ceramic capacitor suitable for this application in terms of performance? I have seen that nowadays smd high voltage ceramic capacitor are available at low price.

Comment: what kind of capacitance would you use?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but x or y rated capacitors are not available in ceramic but they certainly are for film types. Now go check why x or y rated capacitors are needed for this type of application.

Comment: Y caps are found in ceramic and some are X as well.  I don't believe DC link caps are usually X or Y however.  The advantage of film caps is size.  Film caps for link applications are found into the 10s of uf at least.  There are DC link ceramics but I don't know to what size.  The advantage of ceramics would be exceptionally low ESR and ESL, often a big deal for link caps.  DC link films often have special construction to get low ESR/ESL.  Sometimes VERY special.